# Testing Angular Filter That Returns An Array with Jasmine

Tags: arrays, angularjs, unit-testing, filter, jasmine

So, I'm having issues testing an angular filter that takes an array that has previously been sorted by a group property. It uses a flag property to indicate that the item is the first observation of that group, and then false for subsequent observations.

I'm doing this to have a category header in the UI with an ng-repeat directive.

When I test the filter, the output does not return the array with the flags unless I create new objects for the return array. This is a problem, because it causes an infinite loop when running in a webpage. The code works in the webpage when it just adds a flag property to the input object.

Is there some additional step I should be taking to simulate how angular handles filters so that it outputs the proper array?

This is what my test looks like right now.

```
describe('IsDifferentGroup', function() {
   var list, itemOne, itemTwo, itemThree;

   beforeEach(module("App.Filters"));

   beforeEach(function () {
    list = [];

    itemOne = new ListItem();
    itemTwo = new ListItem();
    itemThree = new ListItem();
    itemOne.group = "A";
    itemTwo.group = "B";
    itemThree.group = "C";

    list.push(itemOne);
    list.push(itemOne);
    list.push(itemOne);
    list.push(itemOne);
    list.push(itemTwo);
    list.push(itemThree);
    list.push(itemThree);
    list.push(itemThree);
    list.push(itemThree);
    list.push(itemThree);
});

it('should flag the items true that appear first on the list.', (inject(function (isDifferentGroupFilter) {
    expect(list.length).toBe(10);

    var result = isDifferentGroupFilter(list);

    expect(result[0].isDifferentGroup).toBeTruthy();
    expect(result[1].isDifferentGroup).toBeFalsy();
    expect(result[4].isDifferentGroup).toBeTruthy();
    expect(result[5].isDifferentGroup).toBeTruthy();
    expect(result[6].isDifferentGroup).toBeFalsy();
    expect(result[9].isDifferentGroup).toBeFalsy();

})));

});
```

And here is something like the code with the filter:

```
var IsDifferentGroup = (function () {
function IsDifferentGroup() {
    return (function (list) {
        var arrayToReturn = [];
        var lastGroup = null;

        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            if (list[i].group != lastGroup) {
                list[i].isDifferentGroup = true;
                lastAisle = list[i].group;
            } else {
                list[i].isDifferentGroup = false;
            }
            arrayToReturn.push(list[i]);
        }

        return arrayToReturn;
    });
}
return IsDifferentGroup;
})();
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my issue.

When I was passing the items into the list, I just pushed a pointer to an item multiple times. I was not passing in unique objects so the flag was being overridden by the following flag in the array(I think). So, I just newed up 10 unique objects using a loop, pushed them into the array and ran it through the filter. And it worked.

I'm not entirely sure my analysis is correct about the override, because itemTwo was not being flagged as unique when it was the only itemTwo in the array. But the test is working as I would expect now so I'm going to stop investigating the issue.